# Displaying a dynamic list of images with corresponding text/URLs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, list, dynamic

I have a web service which returns me a list of images, it's titles and URL's that the user needs to be redirected to when clicked on these images in XML format. I need to build a dynamic list of these clickable images aligned horizontally and I need to do this using jQuery or javascript. Are there any known components which do this? Do I need to write from scratch? If I do then how do I go about it?

Comment: use `$.ajax` to retrieve the xml and then you need to parse it to html. There are lots of tutorials on web how to do this , keywords `ajax xml tutorial`. WHat does xml look like, and what does output need to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)  to get the XML into a jQuery object and then iterate through the object to populate a knockout observable array of observable objects.  See http://knockoutjs.com/ for examples of how to use knockout for dynamic binding.  I'd use an unordered list to render each of the images with titles and links.  You can style the list any way you want.

Browse to the knockout.js tutorial - http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections Nd in your javascript, add:

```
function SiteItem(u, t, s) {
    var self = this;
    self.url = ko.observable(u);
    self.title = ko.observable(t);
    self.imgSrc = ko.observable(s);
}

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Editable data
    self.items= ko.observableArray([
        new SiteItem('http://www.google.com/', 'Test', 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'),
        new SiteItem('http://www.google.com/', 'Test', 'http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png')
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

then in the HTML, the knockout template for the UL:

```
<h2>Your images</h2>

<ul class="horizontal-list" id="sites" data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li class="site" data-bind="attr: { 'data-url': url }">
    <a data-bind="text: title, attr: { href: url }"></a>
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: imgSrc, alt: title }" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Parsing the XML is not the problem, really. The problem is once I have an object with the list of images with their details, how do I generate a list of images dynamically.

Comment: use knockout to generate the list

Comment: viperguynaz - can you send me an example? I couldn't find any helpful links with the images ...

Comment: added a code example to the answer - there are plenty of tutorials and examples on http://knockoutjs.com/

Comment: Thanks viperguynaz. I'm really trying to do a basic example and this doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/n3w4C/

Comment: updated the answer - http://jsfiddle.net/viperguynaz/GkP3s/2/ - in jsfiddle - don't use doc, head, body tags and in the js, don't use script tags - there is a great tutorial on knockout.js @ http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro that implements jsfiddle like interface